# If statement inside for loop in android

Tags: android, listview, if-statement, for-loop

I am creating Listview in my Android App.In My CustomAdapter I have anIf-statement inside a For loop. Let's see the Code.

```
public String[] timePartOne = {"10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:30 AM"};
public boolean[] avaibleOne = {true, false, true, false};
```

in My CustomAdapter Class I have used this condition :

```
for(int i = 0; i < timePartOne.length;i++) {

                        if (avaibleOne[i] == true) {
                            holder.textview.setText(timePartOne[i]);
                            holder.textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0072BA"));
                        } else {
                            holder.textview.setText(timePartOne[i]);
                            holder.textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#e6e6e6"));
                            holder.textview.setPaintFlags(holder.textview.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                        }

                }
```

But I don't know why this loop is `continuously run`. As per the review the loop will run `4 time`. Because `timePartOne.length is 4`.

Any help be Appreciated.

Comment: what is avaibleOne ? post the whole class here please . the fault may be outside.

Comment: @SagarNayak  it writing mistake.

Comment: @cricket_007 what you say i can't understand please explain brief so i can understand.

Comment: @Harshad, the for-loop should run 4 times. The problem is likely elsewhere. Please post more code.

Comment: @RvdK in my getView I have only that code no more code in there.

Comment: A loop is a circle. An if statement is a separation of paths. There is no such thing as an "if loop"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use `for` in `getView` method of adapter. just use `position` parameter of `getView` method.

```
int i = position /*parameter of getView method */;

        if (avaibleOne[i] == true) {
            holder.textview.setText(timePartOne[i]);
            holder.textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0072BA"));
        } else {
            holder.textview.setText(timePartOne[i]);
            holder.textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#e6e6e6"));
            holder.textview.setPaintFlags(holder.textview.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        }
```

Comment: getView() is called everytime the list want to refresh its view (scroll).